# Why I can use relative path and absolute path on may MacVim?

Tags: macos, macvim

I just started to learning C Language.
My system is OS X 10.10 and MacVim 7.4.383 compiled by myself because I need it support python3.
But I find if a just double cilck the MacVim.app and `:open ~/Desktop/something.c`, it will tell me that something.c is a new file. But I did have a file called something.c on my Desktop, and I search the reason of situation, it seem to there is something about environment variable, so I follow the guide to add this code to file:///etc/launchd.conf

```
setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

and restart my computer, it didn't change anything
and my /etc/bashrc is

## System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\d \A  \u @ \H \w  #\#: \$ '

# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
# Tell the terminal about the working directory at each prompt.
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ] && [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    update_terminal_cwd() {
        # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL,
        # including the host name to disambiguate local vs.
        # remote connections. Percent-escape spaces.
    local SEARCH=' '
    local REPLACE='%20'
    local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
    }
    PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
fi

# ===== ===== ===== =====

# Custom Setting
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxfxaxdxcxegedabagacad
export HISTSIZE=250

# Setting PATH for KDE
export KDEDIRS=$KDEDIRS:$HOME/Library/Preferences/KDE:/usr/local/kde4
export PATH=/usr/local/kde4/bin:$PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/kde4/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
launchctl setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/kde4/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export XDG_DATA_HOME=$HOME/Library/Preferences/KDE/share
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/kde4/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share

# Setting PATH for MySQL 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/

# Setting PATH for Node.js and NPM
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/node
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/npm

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

And if I used absolute path like this

```
:open /Users/XXX/Desktop/something.c
```

it will print an error

```
E479:Not match
E32:No file name
```

So, what can I do to make the MacVim work like just under linux, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:open` is not used for opening a file. You need to use `:edit` or `:e` command for that.

You can just use:

```
:e /Users/XXX/Desktop/something.c
```

Also `$PATH` doesn't have any impact on `:e` command.

As per `vim` help:

> 1: **Simulated command**                  *simulated-command*
>
> This command is in Vi, but Vim only simulates it:
>
> ```
> *:o* *:op* *:open* :[range]o[pen]         Works like |:visual|: end Ex mode.
> {Vi: start editing in open mode}
>
> :[range]o[pen] /pattern/  As above, additionally move the cursor to the
>           column where "pattern" matches in the cursor
>           line.
> ```
>
> **Vim does not support open mode, since it's not really useful.  For
>   those situations where ":open" would start open mode Vim will leave Ex
>   mode, which allows executing the same commands, but updates the whole
>   screen instead of only one line.**